# Angular redirect to current page

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a modal where I am using a custom directive which closes the modal after submit. This works. Next I'm wondering how I can then refresh the current page the user is on in angular. I've tried $location.path("/"); and it works but it redirects to root page instead of whatever page the user is currently on. What can I do to redirect to the current page.

URL Looks Like This
index.angular.html#/profile/

Custom Directive Looks like this

```
// Custom directive to close modal upon submit
app.directive('myModal', function($location) {
   return {
     restrict: 'A',
     link: function(scope, element, attr) {
       scope.dismiss = function() {
           element.modal('hide');
           $location.path("/");
       };
     }
 };
});
```

Comment: Though the solution will be the simple one ? Why do you want to do so ? Maintaining the state should not be difficult in `angular`

Comment: I am using the modal to add a record to the database which I am showing in the UI. Technically if I just need to update the $scope which is bound to the table I am showing would it be better to just refresh the $scope I am using? If so how?

Comment: You can achieve this using callback function(`success`) and update the `model`

Answer (score 0):

Can you just use the $window service?

```
$window.location.reload();
```

Don't forget that you need to inject $window into your directive.

Comment: I guess he can not. Because after loading the modal, the URL changes. It just reloads the modal's URL.

Comment: Let's see... you're probably right, but modal doesn't typically touch the url on the main page ... it loads the view and then pops the whole thing into a couple of divs.  Once the modal divs are removed, he wants to refresh the page with the current url.

Comment: Normally, yes, this is what a "modal" should do. But I guess OP uses his own mysterious type of modal which probably touches the URL. That's why just `.modal('hide')`ing it was not sufficient.

Comment: No way man ... I'll bet you $1 that he comes back with a "thanks for the tip" once he wakes up from his nap ;-)

Comment: Oops... I lost already!  he just changed the question in the comments to "if i want to just update the scope instead of refreshing the window, how do I do that" ...

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me in a similar scenario.

```
  this.router.navigate(['path/to'])
            .then(() => {
              window.location.reload();
            });
```